# Twilio Outbound IVR

Tags: twilio, ivr, outbound

I want to set up IVR for outbound calls on Twilio number .
So how can I set up it ?If it can be setup using c# language then how can I deal with "To" and "From" number parameters to set them dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look of following links, they might help you,
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/ivr-phone-tree-csharp-mvc

For making call:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call

You can pass to and from number as a parameter to the function.
or do you have something different requirement, if yes, please elaborate, then i can assist you more deeply in c#.

Comment: My requirement is just to have IVR on the outbound calls .And problem is that I an unable to  make it dynamic so that no need to pass hard code numbers.I had integrated twilio with zoho crm and want to make calls from zoho crm to the customer and must be automated.

Comment: I don't have knowledge of ZOHO CRM, but why you cannot pass ToNumber as a parameter to the function, FromNumber will be your twilio number that you have purchased and used to make calls, you can set that in somewhere in environmental variable or config settings from where you can read that.